# Further explanation needed :Finding all $z$ such that the modulus of $f(z)=e^{(z+1)/(z-1)}$ is equal to/at most $1$

Tags: complex-analysis

I was solving a previous exam paper and there I got stuck on the following problem:

> Let $f(z)=e^{\frac{z+1}{z-1}}$. Then find all $z \in \Bbb C$ for which
>
> 1. $|f(z)|=1$,
> 2. $|f(z)|\le 1$.

Any idea about how to tackle this problem will be highly appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: With $|f(z)|$ I assume you denote the absolute value of the function $f$?

Comment: @Mhenni and @O.L.: Be more careful with suggested edits. The suggested edit removed the `complex-analysis`-tag and added `calculus` which does not seem justified in this case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $z=r e^{i\theta}$, where $r\ge 0$ and $\theta\in \mathbb{R}$. 
Then 
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
|f(r,\theta)| 
&=& \exp\left(\frac{r^2-1}{r^2-2r\cos\theta+1}\right) \\
&=& \exp\left(\frac{r^2-1}{(r-1)^2+2r(1-\cos\theta)}\right).
\end{eqnarray*}$$

I. If $\cos\theta = 1$, $|f| = \exp\left(\frac{r+1}{r-1}\right)$. 
In this case $|f|\ne 1$ for any $r$. 
However, $|f|<1$ for $r<1$.

II. If $\cos\theta\ne 1$, $(r-1)^2+2r(1-\cos\theta) > 0$. 
Therefore, $|f| = 1$ for $r=1$ and $|f|<1$ for $r<1$.

We find, $|f| = 1$ for all
$z = e^{i\theta}$,
where $\theta \ne 2\pi n$ and $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.
This is the unit circle with $(1,0)$ deleted.

In addition, $|f|\le 1$ for all 
$z = r e^{i\theta}$
such that 
(1) $r=1$ and $\theta\ne 2\pi n$ or 
(2) $r<1$ and $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$. 
This is the unit circle and its interior with $(1,0)$ deleted.

The results agree with those of @JonClaus, who used Cartesian coordinates.

[Here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+exp%282%28x-1%29%2F%28%28x-1%29%2a%2a2%2By%2a%2a2%29%2B1%29%2C+x%3D-1+to+1%2C+y%3D-1+to+1) is a three dimensional plot of $|f|$ above the complex plane.

Answer (score 1):

If $w$ is any complex number, $|e^w| =  e^{\operatorname{Re}(w)}$, so you are trying to respectively find the $z$ for which $\operatorname{Re}({z +1 \over z- 1}) = 0$ and $\operatorname{Re}({z +1 \over z- 1}) \leq 0$. To figure out the details of which $z$ satisfy these, knowledge of Möbius transformations are helpful, but you can work them out by hand too.

Comment: Using your suggestion,I see that $Re \left(\frac{z+1}{z-1}\right)=0$ gives $|z|=1$ and $Re \left(\frac{z+1}{z-1}\right)\le 0$ gives $|z|\le 1$.Am I right ,sir?

Comment: No... try plugging in some values, you'll see that isn't correct.

Comment: I do not know where I went wrong but I just put $z=x+iy,$ and then simple calculation gives me $Re \left({z+1 \over z-1}\right)={x^2+y^2-1 \over P},\text{where} P=(x-1)^2+y^2$ that means $Re \left({z+1 \over z-1}\right)=0 \implies x^2+y^2=1 \implies |z|=1.$Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Let $ z = a + bi, (a, b) \in \mathbb{R}^2 $. Hence $$\begin{align*} \left|e^{\frac{z+1}{z-1}}\right| &= \left|e^{\frac{(a + 1 + bi)(a - 1 - bi)}{(a - 1 + bi)(a - 1 - bi)}} \right| \\&= \left|\ e^{\frac{a^2 - 1 + b^2 -2bi}{(a - 1)^2 + b^2}}\ \ \right| \\ &= \left|\ e^{ \frac{a^2 -1 + b^2}{(a - 1)^2 + b^2}}\ \ \ \ \ \right|\cdot\left|e^{-\frac{2bi}{(a-1)^2 +b^2}}\right|\\&=\ \ e ^{\frac{a^2 - 1 + b^2}{(a - 1)^2 + b^2)}}\end{align*}$$
Hence, the modulus is $ 1 $ when $ a^2 + b^2 = 1 $, which is a unit circle. Note that the point $ (1, 0) $ should be excluded because $ f(1) $ is not defined.

Also, the modulus is less than $1 $ on the entirety of the disk that is contained by that circle, i.e. $ a^2 + b^2 < 1 $.